# Can Cisco Anywhere VPN monitor/log what devices on a wifi are accessing if one of those devices is on it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

So if person A connects through the VPN to the free Masons HQ, using their internet policies etc. Do you know if Cisco VPN has anyway of logging / allowing  those pesky Masons to log what other devices sharing person A's connection (who are not themselves connected to the VPN) are accessing? Ie in a coffee shop for instance, if one customer connects to a site through the VPN, can the site theoretically see what everyone in the coffee shop is doing at the time of connection/tunnelling? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all practical purposes no.

Person A connects to the Mason HQ via an encrypted tunnel over their device's internet connection.  unless the patrons of the coffee shop are routing through Person A's computer to reach the internet (as opposed to collectively routing through the coffee shop wireless access point) there is no way for the Cisco AnyConnect VPN to be aware of what their traffic looks like.

Alternatively, If Person A was not a Mason but instead a networking ninja and gained access to the coffee shop router and set up the tunnel endpoint there, then all the patrons traffic could route through Mason HQ VPN and no ones secret handshakes would be free from prying eyes.

Comment: haha thanks for speaking my lingo Timmy! I wish i had more rep to vote you up. I take it a networking ninja would have to have admin access to the router itself right? They couldn't subtly (as ninjas do) wait for the VPN to open and then jump out with some cunning plan that person A was unaware of?

Comment: they couldn't ,  the vpn is a secure tunnel.